# retrieving certain keys from a returned JSON in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, json

I am sending a `JSON encoded POST` type to a server of mine which reads the sent information in `PHP` and decodes it there.  Now when I re-encode it and send it back it works perfectly and I can `NSLog` the response but my issue is how do I get a specific section of the response?

Here is an example response:

```
 responseString: {"status":"ok","code":0,"original request":{"username":"test"
`,"password":"test"}}`
```

Suggestions, thoughts?

Comment: specific section of the response? You mean parsing JSON response?

Comment: parse JSON data with NSJSONSerialization and then you can access the data in the dictionary as described by GoGreen

Comment: Please read the SO faq.You should spend reasonable time searching for answers before asking a question. There are very much information about this elsewehere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are receiving is actually a '*dictionary of objects*'. You can separate the data in the above code as follows:

First, serialize the response data using JSON serialization as follows:

```
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:nil error:&error];
```

You may then separate the dictionary as you wish.
For instance, if you want to retrieve the value for *"status"*, you may use:

```
NSString *status = [responseDictionary objectForKey:@"status"];
```

Or, if you want to retrieve *"original request"* which is another dictionary, you may use:

```
NSDictionary *originalRequest = [responseDictionary objectForKey:@"original request"];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey I am getting an error when trying to do this ` No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'objectForKey:'` and `responseString`  is type `NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Comment: thats because you are applying objectForKey on an NSString class. I had mentioned about this in my answer.

Comment: where are you getting returnData from?

Answer (score 0):

The response received from the server is [JSON](http://json.org) data. 
Here is an excellent tutorial on JSON parsing for iOS and there are plenty of tutorials & docs if you browse.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

In JSON, "{}" represents a dictionary and "[]" is an array. So, try this

```
NSDictionary* originalRequest = [responseString objectForKey:@"original request"];
```

you can dig in further like this,

```
NSString* username = [originalRequest objectForKey:@"username"];
```

I strongly recommend you to read some tutorials on JSON.